# can't debug a Windows Form Program

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

```
Imports mysql.data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private conexion As 
       New MySqlConnection("Server=10.0.0.12;Database=servicioinventariopiramide;
          Uid=pabloponce;Pwd=****;")
    Dim DAFacturas As New MySqlDataAdapter("call sp_FacturasConsultar()", conexion)
    Dim DSFacturas As New DataSet()

DAFacturas.fill(DSFacturas, "Facturas")
grdfacturas.datasource=DSFacturas
grdfacturas.datamember=DSFacturas.table("Facturas").tablename
End Class
```

says that on line 6,7,8 where it says 'DAFacturas', 'grdfacturas' says that ther is a 'declaration expected'

Comment: It is tradition not to post your passwords on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Test your connection from the mysql command line and check if that works: If not, then you have to configure your connection differently.

Comment: You can only call methods from inside another method. When do you want to call `DAFacturas.fill`? When `Form1` is opened? Put it in Form1's `Load` handler.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put executable code directly in a Class.  All executable code should be in methods inside the class.  If you need this code to run when the Form is loaded, then use the `OnLoad` override:

```
Imports mysql.data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        Dim conexion As New MySqlConnection("Server=10.0.0.12;Database=servicioinventariopiramide;
          Uid=pabloponce;Pwd=****;")
        Dim DAFacturas As New MySqlDataAdapter("call sp_FacturasConsultar()", conexion)
        Dim DSFacturas As New DataSet()

        DAFacturas.fill(DSFacturas, "Facturas")
        grdfacturas.datasource=DSFacturas
        grdfacturas.datamember=DSFacturas.table("Facturas").tablename
    End Sub

End Class
```